# How to access DOM from webpack loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-loader

I'm writing a webpack loader for a specific file extension, and I would like to append a custom import to the DOM

```
module.exports = function(source) {
    ...
    document.appendChild(myImport)

    return `export default 'hello'`;
}
```

but the DOM is not accessible

> ReferenceError: document is not defined

### Is there a way to access the DOM from my loader?

My webpack configuration is:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.myextension$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'my-loader'
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the code from loader is going to be ran on a node.js env, which has no power over the dom (browser env). To be able to manipulate the dom, you would have to output a code though loader which would be inserted  on that type of file and then when executed on the browser it would do the modifications.

Something like:

```
module.exports = function(source) {
    return `export default function(){
        document.appendChild(myImport)
    }`;
}
```